# Appium- set capabilities

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I wrote test cases in appium and provided device name,platform version,platform name using code

```
 capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "samsung");
 capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
 capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
 capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

The problem is this test code is supported only in device having these specifications.How to write appium code to fetch the device specification automatically,so that the same test code can be run in any device without providing phone specification in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the details from outside that may be in excel sheet or config files etc and pass to the capabilities

Before calling capabilities, read the data available in the file and pass the same to the capabilities

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the O.S capabilities.

```
String deviceName= android.os.Build.MODEL; 
String verion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

you can used above in your code like

```
 capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
 capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", verion );
 capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
 capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

**platformName :** It should be same as we are running it on android O.S.

**app :** It should be different for the different application it varies

Hope it helps you.